# How to total value of checkbox when I check and update value immediately after unchek it using jquery?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

```js
$('#r4').change(function() {
  var sum = 0;
  $('#r4:checked').each(function() {
    sum += parseInt($(this).val());
  })

  $(".totcheck").val(sum);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12" style="background: whitesmoke; margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <h3 style="text-align: left">Row 4</h3>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12" id="Spirit" style="text-align: left;">
        <li>
          <label class="control control--checkbox">Content A
            <input type="checkbox" id="r4" value="1"/>
            <div class="control__indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label class="control control--checkbox"> Content B
            <input type="checkbox" id="r4" value="1"/>
            <div class="control__indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label class="control control--checkbox"> Content C
            <input type="checkbox" id="r4" value="1"/>
            <div class="control__indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label class="control control--checkbox"> Content D
            <input type="checkbox" id="r4" value="1"/>
            <div class="control__indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12" style="background: #ffdcdc; margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <h3 style="text-align: left;">Result</h3>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12" style="text-align: left;">
        <p>Total number of statements checked: <input type="number" name="total" disabled class="totcheck" style="float:none; margin-left: 10px;" />
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a several div with different id of checkbox. I want to accumulate the value of checkbox when I check,and re-update the value if I uncheck a box.

For example:
If I checked content A and content B, it will update total value to 2, when I unchecked content B, it automatic update total value to 1.

Comment: **ID should be unique use class instead**

Comment: @guradio Thank you! It work after I change to class.

Comment: glad to help mate always remember ID should always be unique in context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

id must be unique, so in case of id it only gets the first element, use classes or specify the selector

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    var sum = 0;
    
    $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
        sum += parseInt($(this).val());
    })

    $(".totcheck").val(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12" style="background: whitesmoke; margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <h3 style="text-align: left">Row 4</h3>
      <div class="row" >
        <div class="col-sm-12" id="Spirit" style="text-align: left;">
          <li>
            <label class="control control--checkbox">Content A
              <input type="checkbox" id="r4" value="1"/>
              <div class="control__indicator"></div>
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label class="control control--checkbox"> Content B
              <input type="checkbox" id="r4" value="1"/>
              <div class="control__indicator"></div>
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label class="control control--checkbox"> Content C
              <input type="checkbox" id="r4" value="1"/>
              <div class="control__indicator"></div>
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label class="control control--checkbox"> Content D
              <input type="checkbox" id="r4" value="1"/>
              <div class="control__indicator"></div>
            </label>
          </li>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12" style="background: #ffdcdc; margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <h3 style="text-align: left;">Result</h3>
      <div class="row" >
        <div class="col-sm-12" style="text-align: left;">
          <p>Total number of statements checked: <input type="number" name="total" disabled class="totcheck" style="float:none; margin-left: 10px;" />
          </p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

By the way, here is a much shorter solution.

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
     $(".totcheck").val($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12" style="background: whitesmoke; margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <h3 style="text-align: left">Row 4</h3>
      <div class="row" >
        <div class="col-sm-12" id="Spirit" style="text-align: left;">
          <li>
            <label class="control control--checkbox">Content A
              <input type="checkbox" id="r4" value="1"/>
              <div class="control__indicator"></div>
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label class="control control--checkbox"> Content B
              <input type="checkbox" id="r4" value="1"/>
              <div class="control__indicator"></div>
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label class="control control--checkbox"> Content C
              <input type="checkbox" id="r4" value="1"/>
              <div class="control__indicator"></div>
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label class="control control--checkbox"> Content D
              <input type="checkbox" id="r4" value="1"/>
              <div class="control__indicator"></div>
            </label>
          </li>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12" style="background: #ffdcdc; margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <h3 style="text-align: left;">Result</h3>
      <div class="row" >
        <div class="col-sm-12" style="text-align: left;">
          <p>Total number of statements checked: <input type="number" name="total" disabled class="totcheck" style="float:none; margin-left: 10px;" />
          </p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use class instead of id in chack box..see below code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.r4').change(function() {
  var sum = 0;
  $('.r4:checked').each(function() {
    sum += parseInt($(this).val());
  })

  $(".totcheck").val(sum);

});
    });
</script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12" style="background: whitesmoke; margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <h3 style="text-align: left">Row 4</h3>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12" id="Spirit" style="text-align: left;">
        <li>
          <label class="control control--checkbox">Content A
            <input type="checkbox" class="r4" value="1"/>
            <div class="control__indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label class="control control--checkbox"> Content B
            <input type="checkbox" class="r4" value="1"/>
            <div class="control__indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label class="control control--checkbox"> Content C
            <input type="checkbox" class="r4" value="1"/>
            <div class="control__indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label class="control control--checkbox"> Content D
            <input type="checkbox" class="r4" value="1"/>
            <div class="control__indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```